# Limitations when exporting JNI native methods to Java

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I am working on Android, where I have a function exposed via JNI so it can be consumed by the Java part of my app:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_demo_android_some_MyClass_init(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
   // code here
}
```

On the Java side, i have a class called *demo.android.MyClass* in which i declare this method as native.

This class is used as a "wrapper" for the native functions, and all calls must be done using it.

My question is whether there are any limitations on this class?

I am experiencing some issues, which i am not sure are related, when declaring and creating an instance of this class as final (to be used inside an anonymous class implementation):

> private final MyClass c = new MyClass();
>
> c.init();

Are there any limitations then? is this case valid? (and so, my problem is elsewhere)

Comment: Approximately the same works fine for me in my code. What problems are you facing?

Comment: The function is `demo.android.some.MyClass.init`, the question says `demo.android.MyClass`, which isn't the same.  Assuming that's a typo, please quantify the issues you're experiencing -- compiler error?  Runtime failure?  Paste the error message into your question.

Comment: You are experiencing *what* issues?